# Error creating WebGL context. Three js chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I'm getting the error

```
Error creating WebGL context.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getExtension' of null
```

This is happening on google chrome 71 but I find it odd because if I open up dev tool and refresh the page it works perfectly fine I'm at a loss to what is causing this any idea's ?

It's worked perfectly fine untill today nothing has changed on the PC or browser. My drivers are all up to date, webgl is enabled...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently it's a browser and graphic card issue

> mrdoob: The graphics card is only one of the reasons why the context
> can't be created

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4927

This seems to be why unless anyone else has any other ideas...
The issue is on going and not fixed it would be interesting to know why this happens though and why opening dev tools and refreshing resolves the issue for me.

Apparently for me this was due to my graphic card being blacklisted because it's old.

Comment: I am getting this error in Chrome: "THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context." but it works fine in Firefox.

Comment: Same here. Works fine in Firefox not in Chrome. Older Macbook Pro With integrated graphics, but never had problems before..

Answer (score 14):

if you have two GPU installed on your system you might want to try to enable
*Override software rendering list*
in chrome://flags/

Comment: This made it for me ! I do not have 2 GPU, just running chromium in a Debian VM and this solved it !

Comment: Worked for me. And continued to work even after disabling it.

Answer (score 5):

The fix for me was manually enabling WebGL acceleration under Chrome’s feature flags: chrome://flags/

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this several times with THREE.js. It arises for me once memory resources are shared, abandoned, or overwhelmed, for example:

1. I have a good render loop but then I introduce **long tasks**.
2. I perform extensive, continuous testing. As I modify **live settings** in Chrome Inspector, THREE does not reflect all changes without fail. Memory may not be released until I restart.
3. I **leave the program running** overnight. The next morning the browser is froze, black, OOM...
4. I use **multiple instances of a resource**, for example
   Web Audio and Magenta Music. The quality may perceptibly degrade and
   throw its own errors, but... I will also encounter worse silent
   errors. For example when I also stream music in another tab, or click
   audio/video media on Twitter... frozen browser, black screen, WebGL
   context loss.

Answer (score 2):

I updated my graphic drivers (NVIDIA) and didn't restart chrome nor the PC, and was having this issue.

I just restarted the PC and now it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your chrome://settings/
2. Click on **System**, on the left side panel
3. Turn on **"Use hardware acceleration when available"**
4. Click **"Relaunch"**

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Error creating webGL Context in three.js.min ver 93
I had the same problem with Chrome version 104.5112.102 and managed to fix it by going to Chrome, Settings, and switching off the
Use hardware acceleration when available.
the graphics card is an old GE Force 8600 card running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved for me by simply installing the latest and restarting my browser - thought I'd add it here to hopefully save some future soul from wasting an hour like i did.

Comment: Installing the latest chrome version?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I restarted my computer and the error did not appear again. You can try doing this before you do anything more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem, it has to do with the Google Chrome browser, what you have to do is click on the three dots on the top right in the browser, and look for settings. There you open the settings and put "Hardware Acceleration" in the search box, activate the switch, and click "Restart".