# Spline giving runtime error : A WebGL context could not be created. Reason: Failed to create a WebGL2 context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spline

Devs I am integrating spline 3D models into my react app. It was working fine but suddenly the 3d model stopped showing in my webpage and gave a bunch of errors in my console.
The error looks like the one below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPVxr.png)

I don't know what actually happening I need help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you are loading the scene in React through the URL
(e.g. `<Spline scene="https://prod.spline.design/xxxxx/scene.splinecode" />`) or if you've exported the scene already in Three.js. If it's the latter, try the first approach and see if that works.

If not, this seems indicative of a problem with either your GPU or how your browser uses it. There was [an issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4927) in the Three.js repo talking about this issue and, according to mrdoob himself:

> mrdoob: Failing to create a WebGL context is most of the times due to the graphics card being too old and/or the manufacturer no longer updating its drivers. Or the drivers not being reliable enough (ie. Linux drivers).

Try to update the GPU drivers (in case they got corrupted). If possible, try using another browser (e.g. Firefox) to see if it works.

[If you have two GPU installed on your system you might want to try to enable Override software rendering list in `chrome://flags/`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65703674/20281592)