# Preventing the entire page to crash on THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a 3D project on a react/next site that causes some problems in Chrome for some users. The error (`THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context.`) causes the entire page to crash. Not on all browsers and not on all machines. However, on one Macbook on Chrome always. I suspect it might be related to this [Error creating WebGL context. Three js chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232528/error-creating-webgl-context-three-js-chrome)

I'm afraid I won't be able to fix the root cause for the crash at this point, but I need to find a way to "save" the rest of the page. So that when it happens only the affected section is gone, but not the entire page.
I tried to put it in a `try/catch` but that did not help (maybe because it is an "Unhandled Runtime Error"?!).

**Is there way to prevent the entire page to crash?**

The section in question is in a `<Suspense>`

```js
<Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
  <Canvas
    dpr={Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio, 2)}
    camera={{ fov: 43, near: 0.1, far: 2000, position: [0, 0, 8] }}
  >
    <ambientLight intensity={0.7} />
    <pointLight position={[5, 5, 5]} />
    <Object3D file={file} />
  </Canvas>
</Suspense>
```

There is no error when I remove the `<Canvas>`, can I "isolate" the `<Canvas>` somehow?

PS: We are for now stuck on react 17.0.2, although we are considering upgrading to 18 in the near future. That also means we cannot upgrade `@react-three/fiber` to v8 (currently on 7.0.29)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding error boundaries with [react-error-boundary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary) lib, it is supposed to handle runtime errors